# GetLastError returns success after InternetSetCookie returns false

Tags: c#, .net, wininet

Using .NET 4.6.2, coding in C#

Having a problem for just a customer on a handful of their machines. When the user is in Local Administrator group, everything works fine but when they remove them from Local Administrators, it would appear `InternetSetCookie` returns false, but `GetLastWin32Error` returns success.

I concluded `InternetSetCookie` is returning false, because I fail to see any line above it could possibly throw such an exception. But I guess anything is possible.

```
[DllImport("wininet.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
static extern bool InternetSetCookie(string lpszUrl, string lpszCookieName, string lpszCookieData);

private bool SetUriCookie(CookieContainer container, Uri uri, string cookieName){
    bool bRetVal = false;
    try{
        Cookie cookie = container.GetCookies(uri)[cookieName];
        string cookieValue = cookie == null ? "" : cookie.Value;
        DateTime cookieExpire = cookie == null ? DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(2) : cookie.Expires;
        string cookieData = string.Format("{0};expires={1}", cookieValue, cookieExpire.ToString("R"));
        bRetVal = InternetSetCookie(uri.ToString(), cookieName, cookieData);
        if (!bRetVal) throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Logger.LogError(e, "Exception thrown attempting to store '{0}' cookie", cookieName);
    }
    return bRetVal;
}
```

This is what logged is:

> Exception thrown attempting to store 'xxxxx' cookie Error: The operation completed successfully

I have reason to believe the cookie is being stored, even though the API returns false. I have yet to confirm that. Any suggestions on how I should proceed?

Comment: This is job for the customer's IT staff to sort out.  Starting by winnowing down on the crapware that always hangs off a HTTP socket, anti-malware and whatnot.  Fwiw, the framework uses InternetSetCookieEx().

Comment: @HansPassant, I would agree if the cookie wasn't being saved, however, it would be nice to give them a clue what to look for. But it appears the cookie is being saved and obviously would impact my error handling code.

Comment: @HansPassant, what .NET function can I use to call InternetSetCookieEx

Comment: It is not accessible.  https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#WindowsBase/Shared/MS/Win32/UnsafeNativeMethodsOther.cs,c8e0978c08658ecb